# Domain of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am confused about this problem: Find the domain of the function, $$f(x)=\frac{x^3-1}{2x^2+5}.$$ I'm guessing it's all real numbers but the book gives a different answer.

---

The book gave $$(-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,0)\cup (0,\infty)$$ as the answer.

Comment: What answer does the book give? It's possible there is a typo. The function you have written down does indeed have all real numbers as its (natural) domain.

Comment: I have added the book's answer

Comment: The answer you write has nothing to do with the function you give. Are you *positive* you are looking at the right pair question/answer? Maybe that's the answer to a different question? If not, then rest assured that answer is completely, totally, and utterly incorrect.

Comment: Thanks very much. The online version of the book gave the above answer. So I got a copy of the book itself, and it gave the answer to be $(-\infty, \infty)$. I guess it's just a typo in the online version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book has goofed.  You have $2x^2 + 5 \ge 5 > 0$  for all real $x$.  Since the denominator has no real zeroes, the function is defined everywhere.  Its natural domain in the entire real line.